# using dbms_pipe to insert data coming from heavy transaction

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

I have an application where very frequently data is coming. Data is string[word] and int value, which i am inserting into database for further processing. Insort I am using mysql C++  connection.

I am accessing mysql from c++ envioronment. Initially I though to call insert query for each in coming data and insert into database. Then got suggestion that it will become very costly and unappropriate to make query for each such insert when there very high frequency of data insert.

I got suggestion to use `dbms_pile`. I have not used it before, I read documentation and got the concept.

I think this feature : `Triggers and stored procedures can send debugging information to a pipe. Another session can keep reading out of the pipe and display it on the screen or write it to a file` this feature will suffice me requirement, right?  Rather write it to file I can insert into database without display. Ref: [Dbms_pipe](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_pipe.htm#i1003916)

1. Will it suffice?
2. Will it make any difference?
3. can someone show me piece of implementation or reference?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using Oracle or MySql? You refer to Oracle pipes but saying that you're using mysql connection. What is it then?

Comment: @peterm: I am using Mysql. Does dbms_pipe could not be used by mysql?

Comment: I far as I understand no it couldn't be used with MySql.

Comment: I removed the Oracle tag since it doesn't sound like you're using Oracle.  `dbms_pipe` is a PL/SQL package that is part of Oracle.  It isn't something that exists on MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach to consider:

1. Accumulate appropriate portions (depending on the frequency) of incoming data in a local file in a delimited form (e.g. comma, or tab delimited)
2. Once in a while start a new file and load a previous one into the database with [`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html). It's **the fastest** way to load batches of data in MySql.
3. After successful load delete the file

If for some reason you can't use files for buffering at least use multi insert syntax

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2,...) 
VALUES (value1, value2, ...),(value3, value4,...),...
```

building a query string for a batch of data and then execute it at once.

Also take a look at **[Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html)**:

> To optimize insert speed, combine many small operations into a single
>   large operation. **Ideally, you make a single connection, send the data
>   for many new rows at once, and delay all index updates and consistency
>   checking until the very end.**
>
> The time required for inserting a row is determined by the following
>   factors, where the numbers indicate approximate proportions:
>
> Connecting: (3)
>   Sending query to server: (2)
>   Parsing query: (2)
>   Inserting row: (1 × size of row)
>   Inserting indexes: (1 × number of indexes)
>   Closing: (1)

Comment: @petern: But for real time application,  loading data into local file would be costly operation. dont you agree?

Comment: Can you please suggest any alternative without file operation also!

Comment: @Programming_crazy It would be far less costly than to hit the db (presumably over the network) with each individual insert

Comment: @petern: thanks a lot. Implementing above protocol would not send request to database for each query to insert data from user, right? so when it will perform insert; limiting criteria?

Comment: Is it possible replacing mysql by dbms_pipe to talk to direct server? any suggestion about this?

Comment: @Programming_crazy It will be executed when you execute it. It's just a string which you build in your client code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37001/discussion-between-programming-crazy-and-peterm)